# How to mock file system with Laravel and vfsStream? [Laravel 5.1]

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-5.1, vfs-stream

I have request like this:

```
$path = storage_path('testing/unnamed.png');
        $original_name = 'unnamed';
        $mime_type = 'image/png';
        $size = 2192;
        $error = null;
        $test = true;

        $file = new UploadedFile($path, $original_name, $mime_type, $size, $error, $test);



        $response = $this->call('POST', 'games', [
            'name' => 'TEST321',
            'category' => 'test',], [], ['picture' => $file], []);
```

And insted of storing image how can I mock file system?

Also this don't pass laravel mime validation `mimes:jpeg,bmp,png`... Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

laravel allows you to mock any facade by calling the 'shouldReceive' mockery method on it:

```
 File::shouldReceive('move')
        ->with('arguments');
```

[see the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#mocking-facades) for more information

Answer (score 0):

I wrote and use a Laravel 5.4 package, https://packagist.org/packages/stechstudio/laravel-vfs-adapter to let me easily switch to a Virtual File System adapter.